# Need to export a publishing page programmatically including layout and images

Tags: publishing, export

I have a client requirement in which content on a publishing page is extracted and sent to a translator for translation.  The client would like the translator to see what the page looks like in order to get context for the content to be translated. Is there a way to export a publishing page programmatically.  In addition, I need to grab the images for that page as well as the layout information in order to be able to generate an html file.  This sounds like a major task. Any thoughts on how best to proceed?

Saul